# What is the difference in time rates between the volumes where fusion takes place in a star vs outside observers like ships orbiting the star?

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation, stars

I have found information suggesting the difference between the surface and the center isn't even worth worrying about, but since we needed GR to account for Mercury's orbit, I can't help but wonder about more substantial differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GR corrections to Mercury's orbit are *exceedingly tiny* even though the mass of the sun is *exceedingly large* (on a human scale). The time dilation in the center of a star that is supporting fusion as determined by an outside observer at a safe distance can be calculated but it will be small.  Wikipedia has a useful discussion of *gravitational time dilation*.